How to Fetch Exact Transferred Data Size from Network in ReactJS?
I’m working on a ReactJS application and need to measure the exact amount of data transferred over the network for performance monitoring purposes. Specifically, I want to get the transferred size of network requests made by my application.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Using Performance API: I attempted to use the performance.getEntriesByType('resource') method to get resource timings, but the transferSize property doesn’t seem to give me the exact data I need. The results are not always consistent with the actual transferred sizes.
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const resources = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
  const totalSize = resources.reduce((acc, resource) => acc + resource.transferSize, 0);
  console.log('Total transferred size:', totalSize);
});

What I’m looking for:

A reliable method or library to fetch the exact transferred data size for network requests in a ReactJS application.
Example code or approach that could help achieve this goal.


Have you considered just pulling this from the HTTP access logs?

I tried that before, but some of the APIs don’t include the size (Content-Length)

Don't pull the header value into a field.  Use the standard bytes' fields for HTTP

Yeah, I also tried that, but unfortunately, it doesn’t read the size of some APIs, especially for external URLs.

"external URLs"
You would have to obtain those from the web server that the client is connecting to.  Or, you could just use the developer tools in your browser, the network tab, to understand the payloads.
You cannot control third party interfaces or response times unless you have an SLA in a contract.  If your concern about them is so high, then replace the external API with an in-house one where you control the performance
